# proving the lim inf and the lim sup for any listing of rational in the interval (a,b)

Tags: real-analysis

Let $r_n$ be any listing of the rational numbers in the interval $(a,b)$. Establish with proof $\liminf_{n\to \infty} r_n$ and $\limsup_{n\to\infty} r_n$

Please forgive, I have no idea how to write the actual mathematical language on here

We attempted a proof by contradiction but got stuck, we know that the lim inf and the lim sup are guaranteed by the Completeness Axiom but we aren't sure where to go from here. Please help

Comment: Presumably, you mean to establish that lim inf and lim sup are in $\mathbb R$?

Comment: Ah, I think it is the word "establish" that was confusing me. You want to find lim inf and lim sup, with proof, right?

Comment: Yes, and yes it is a course in real analysis so we want to prove they exist in that interval for the reals

Comment: Well, that isn't the same as finding the values - showing something exists is easier than finding the specific values, and the $\liminf$ and $\limsup$ are *not* in $(a,b)$.

Comment: I agree, they exist because their existence is guaranteed by the Completeness Axiom (according to our text), which would be simple enough but our professor agreed that the lim inf rn=a and the lim sup rn=b

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Hint:* There are infinitely many rational numbers in the intervals $(a, a+\varepsilon)$ and $(b-\varepsilon, b)$ for any $\varepsilon>0$.

Comment: Thanks, I did use this fact to establish that there are other things in the interval, but is it enough to assume that the lim inf is not a and prove that it is a? We used a theorem that stated if lim inf rn >a then for some positive integer N x(sub n)>a for n greater than or equal to N. Is that enough?

Comment: Yes, you can assume the contrary and get a contradiction. Clearly $\liminf$ and $\limsup$ are from $[a,b]$. If you suppose $\liminf > a$ or $\limsup < b$, then you get a contradiction.

Comment: Thanks so much! Appreciate the help!